# How many times can new shingles be put over the existing roof?

Tags: roof, glass

How many times can new shingles be put over an existing roof? Two or three times?

Comment: Some municipalities or other local jurisdictions disallow overlays altogether. Ask your local inspector's office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S. for composition shingles it is 2 roofs only, then you must tear off all roofs. Also must tear off if roofing is wet, wood, slate, tile or cement. (See ICC 1510.3)

Comment: Also, shingles must be properly nested for most warranties (or just decent longevity). You can't haphazardly span voids below.